# EX_MEM latch of MIPS pipelining

Tags: mips, verilog

I'm implementing the pipelining of the MIPS architecture and I'm having overutilization in the latch between Execute and Memory modules.

This is my code right now:

```
module ex_mem(
input wire [1:0] ctlwb_out,
input wire [2:0] ctlm_out,
input wire [31:0] adder_out,
input wire aluzero,
input wire [31:0] aluout, readdat2,
input wire [4:0] muxout,
output reg [1:0] wb_ctlout,
output reg branch, memread, memwrite,
output reg [31:0] add_result,
output reg zero,
output reg [31:0] alu_result, rdata2out,
output reg [4:0] five_bit_muxout
);

initial begin
    wb_ctlout <= 0; 
    branch <= 0; 
    memread <= 0; 
    memwrite <= 0;
    add_result <= 0;
    zero <= 0;
    alu_result <= 0; 
    rdata2out <= 0;
    five_bit_muxout <= 0;
end

always @ * begin
#1 //delay


wb_ctlout <= ctlwb_out;
branch <= ctlm_out[2]; //unsure   ] 
memread <= ctlm_out[1]; //unsure  ] -- of correct order
memwrite <= ctlm_out[0]; //unsure ]
add_result <= adder_out;   
zero <= aluzero;
alu_result <= aluout;
rdata2out <= readdat2;
five_bit_muxout <= muxout;
end

endmodule
```

The error I'm getting is:

> [Place 30-58] IO placement is infeasible. Number of unplaced terminals (107) is  >greater than number of available sites (100).
>   The following Groups of I/O terminals have not sufficient capacity: 
>    IO Group: 0 with : SioStd: LVCMOS18   VCCO = 1.8 Termination: 0  TermDir:  Out  RangeId: 1 Drv: 12  has only 100 sites available on device, but needs 107 sites.
>       Term: add_result[0]
>       Term:  add_result[1]
>       Term:  add_result[2]
>       Term:  add_result[3]
>       Term:  add_result[4]
>       Term:  add_result[5]
>       Term:  add_result[6]
>       Term:  add_result[7]
>       Term:  add_result[8]
>       Term:  add_result[9]
>       Term:  add_result[10]
>       Term:  add_result[11]
>       Term:  add_result[12]
>       Term:  add_result[13]
>       Term:  add_result[14]
>       Term:  add_result[15]
>       Term:  add_result[16]
>       Term:  add_result[17]
>       Term:  add_result[18]
>       Term:  add_result[19]
>       Term:  add_result[20]
>       Term:  add_result[21]
>       Term:  add_result[22]
>       Term:  add_result[23]
>       Term:  add_result[24]
>       Term:  add_result[25]
>       Term:  add_result[26]
>       Term:  add_result[27]
>       Term:  add_result[28]
>       Term:  add_result[29]
>       Term:  add_result[30]
>       Term:  add_result[31]
>       Term:  alu_result[0]
>       Term:  alu_result[1]
>       Term:  alu_result[2]
>       Term:  alu_result[3]
>       Term:  alu_result[4]
>       Term:  alu_result[5]
>       Term:  alu_result[6]
>       Term:  alu_result[7]
>       Term:  alu_result[8]
>       Term:  alu_result[9]
>       Term:  alu_result[10]
>       Term:  alu_result[11]
>       Term:  alu_result[12]
>       Term:  alu_result[13]
>       Term:  alu_result[14]
>       Term:  alu_result[15]
>       Term:  alu_result[16]
>       Term:  alu_result[17]
>       Term:  alu_result[18]
>       Term:  alu_result[19]
>       Term:  alu_result[20]
>       Term:  alu_result[21]
>       Term:  alu_result[22]
>       Term:  alu_result[23]
>       Term:  alu_result[24]
>       Term:  alu_result[25]
>       Term:  alu_result[26]
>       Term:  alu_result[27]
>       Term:  alu_result[28]
>       Term:  alu_result[29]
>       Term:  alu_result[30]
>       Term:  alu_result[31]
>       Term:  rdata2out[0]
>       Term:  rdata2out[1]
>       Term:  rdata2out[2]
>       Term:  rdata2out[3]
>       Term:  rdata2out[4]
>       Term:  rdata2out[5]
>       Term:  rdata2out[6]
>       Term:  rdata2out[7]
>       Term:  rdata2out[8]
>       Term:  rdata2out[9]
>       Term:  rdata2out[10]
>       Term:  rdata2out[11]
>       Term:  rdata2out[12]
>       Term:  rdata2out[13]
>       Term:  rdata2out[14]
>       Term:  rdata2out[15]
>       Term:  rdata2out[16]
>       Term:  rdata2out[17]
>       Term:  rdata2out[18]
>       Term:  rdata2out[19]
>       Term:  rdata2out[20]
>       Term:  rdata2out[21]
>       Term:  rdata2out[22]
>       Term:  rdata2out[23]
>       Term:  rdata2out[24]
>       Term:  rdata2out[25]
>       Term:  rdata2out[26]
>       Term:  rdata2out[27]
>       Term:  rdata2out[28]
>       Term:  rdata2out[29]
>       Term:  rdata2out[30]
>       Term:  rdata2out[31]
>       Term:  five_bit_muxout[0]
>       Term:  five_bit_muxout[1]
>       Term:  five_bit_muxout[2]
>       Term:  five_bit_muxout[3]
>       Term:  five_bit_muxout[4]
>       Term:  wb_ctlout[0]
>       Term:  wb_ctlout[1]
>       Term:  branch
>       Term:  memread
>       Term:  memwrite
>       Term:  and zero

Can anyone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
module ex_mem(
input wire [1:0] ctlwb_out,
input wire [2:0] ctlm_out,
input wire [31:0] adder_out,
input wire aluzero,
input wire [31:0] aluout, readdat2,
input wire [4:0] muxout,
output reg [1:0] wb_ctlout,
output reg branch, memread, memwrite,
output reg [31:0] add_result,
output reg zero,
output reg [31:0] alu_result, rdata2out,
output reg [4:0] five_bit_muxout
);





always @ * begin
// #1 //delay
wb_ctlout = 0; 
branch = 0; 
memread = 0; 
memwrite = 0;
add_result = 0;
zero = 0;
alu_result = 0; 
rdata2out = 0;
five_bit_muxout = 0;

wb_ctlout = ctlwb_out;
branch = ctlm_out[2]; //unsure   ] 
memread = ctlm_out[1]; //unsure  ] -- of correct order
memwrite = ctlm_out[0]; //unsure ]
add_result = adder_out;   
zero = aluzero;
alu_result = aluout;
rdata2out = readdat2;
five_bit_muxout = muxout;
end

endmodule
```

Use blocking assignment for combinatorial logic.

## delay is not synthesis stuff

Dont use initial for default value, rather use reset or as shown in code.